# Can't install Kohler bath sink popup stopper

Tags: plumbing

Help! I don't see how to put back this Kohler pop-up stopper. There is a spring in the central cylinder assembly in the sink hole.

I don't see normal threads on the stopper. *Why make this so complicated.*

I tried clockwise, push down and thread etc. It is not latching to anything.

My stopper does not have flanges. The shape of my stopper does not seem to match any of [This](https://support.kohler.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001851913-Identify-the-Correct-Bathroom-Sink-Stopper)
[image]

[image: my stopper is Kohler]

[image: kohler faucet model unknown]

[image: three fang assembly in the hole]

Comment: A photo of the drain hole where this goes may help. How did you get it out, presumably you would do the opposite of the removal process.

Comment: thanks. It was some combination of turning, but was a while back.  Added image

Comment: Attaching another hold pic. Can the rest of assembly in the hold come out easily. Wondering if the 3 fang assembly in the hold can be taken out. Then it may be easier to figure the heart shaped latch mechanism.

Comment: i think that the black part in the top picture comes out of the drain pipe ... there is a part missing ... it may be in the trap ... the heart shaped raceway in the second picture is part of the clicker mechanism ... it engages with a spring loaded pin ... the pin appears to be what is missing

Answer (score 0):

That stopper clearly indicates that the round grey plastic post fits down into a round hole that is centered in the drain assembly. A portion of that centered hole has an approximate half section that fits opposing the flat face of the stopper bottom that has that heart shaped track in it. When that was originally installed some spring applied upward force on the stopper. A rounded follower (very likely a ball bearing type thing) follows along that heart shaped path to support the "up" and "down" positions of the stopper.  Hopefully that ball follower is still captured inside the hole down in the drain in such way that it has stayed in place.

Best case is that you need to use a light to look down into the drain to see what orientation that you have to turn the stopper unit to be able to forcefully push it down into the drain. In this best case the rounded ball follower will allow itself to come into alignment with the heart shaped track and hold the stopper in place even though it is under string pressure in the upward direction.

Worst case is that some portion of the mechanism that follows the heart shaped track in the stopper popped out (and maybe even went down the drain) when you removed the stopper. If the unit responded in this way then you may very well be faced with the replacement of the drain and stopper mechanism.

Since your posting does not include details of how you got the stopper out all evidence points to the removal by a somewhat forceful vertical tugging or prying.

I do see some type of retaining screw that is through the side of the inner core if the drain. It seems likely that this was designed to hold some other inserted part in place. It could be that that part broke and popped out when the drain plug came free.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the post! I did not pry, so less likely to have lost a part. With flash light, I only see a spring spiral and a (seemingly part of sprint that crosses over spiral). No other ball bearing shaped piece I can see. Can't figure an orientation that seem to latch the grey tail. Trying not to force too hard.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that that drain stopper assembly is a Kohler unit or are you just going by the faucet model? The original owner or installer could very well have installed a 3rd party pop-up type of drain assembly. A dead give away would be if there is a round hole in back if the faucet stem where a conventional pull up/push down type of drain operating rod would have been located.

Comment: Could be the "(seemingly part of spring that crosses over spiral)" is what goes in the track, but I can't really see it in the photos.